# Need help with Oracle 11gR2 xe installation on Ubuntu 16.04(64 bit)

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, oracle

I used [sysadmin Notebook](http://sysadminnotebook.blogspot.de/2012/10/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html) to install oracle 11gR2 xe on my ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit) pc. 
The problem is when I executed

> sudo service oracle-xe start

command, it should give some output like

> user@machine:~$ sudo service oracle-xe start
>
> Starting Oracle Net Listener.
>
> Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance.
>
> user@machine:~$

according to the site, but in my case, there's no output. How do I know if it's installed correctly? Also if it's not installed correctly, then how do I remove it completely (so that I can reinstall it)?